# Does upgrading to new version deletes my current package?

Tags: upgrade, package-management

I want to upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 from 12.*.  But i dont want to loose my currently installed packages. Does upgrading to new version deletes my current package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade through the update manager, all of your files and currently installed programs will be preserved.  They will, however, be updated to their latest versions.

Additionally, it will typically ask you at the end if you would like to remove old, obsolete packages that are no longer maintained.  I usually answer yes, but you can answer no if you really want to keep them.